# bot builder form flow with enum

Tags: enums, botframework, formflow

I have a bot builder project using a form flow dialog which is working fine except for a problem with recognising the response to the selection of an enum.

```
[Serializable]
public class ContactBot
{
    [Template(TemplateUsage.EnumSelectOne,"How do you like to be addressed - {||}", "Please select a title to address you by - {||}")]
    public TitleBot? Title { get; set; }

    [Prompt("What's your first name?", FieldCase = CaseNormalization.InitialUpper)]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    [Prompt("and your last name?", FieldCase = CaseNormalization.InitialUpper)]
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    [Prompt("I'll need your email address to confirm the appraisal")]
    [Pattern(RegexConstants.Email)]
    public String Email { get; set; }

    [Prompt("and a phone number, preferably a mobile, to contact you to arrange an appointment")]
    [Pattern(RegexConstants.Phone)]
    public String Phone { get; set; }

    public static IForm<ContactBot> BuildContactForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<ContactBot>()
            .Message("Firstly, can you give me some detail about yourself?")
            .Field(nameof(Title))
            .Field(nameof(FirstName))
            .Field(nameof(LastName))
            .Field(nameof(Email))
            .Field(nameof(Phone))
            .Confirm("You have provided the following: \r\r Name: {Title} {FirstName} {LastName} \r\r Email: {Email} \r\r Phone: {Phone} \r\r Is this correct? ")
            .Build();
    }
```

and the enum

```
public enum TitleBot
{
    Mr,
    Mrs,
    Ms,
    Miss,
    Dr
}
```

When I select Ms, Miss or Dr, the bot accepts this as a valid option and moves to the next prompt. However, when I select Mr or Mrs, I am asked to choose between Mr and Mrs and whatever I choose results in a Mr (or Mrs) is not a title option - What is happening?

Image of bot displaying enumeration:

[image: display]

Image of bot responses to enum selection:

[image: bot responses to enum selection]

Comment: The best solution for you is probably to just use the whole word like Mister, Missus, doctor.  It should eliminate this problem.  Then if you want you would like you can later manipulate it to display as Mr. Mrs. Dr.

Comment: would I be able to have the enumeration display as Mr and return a value of Mister? I would have to use Mistress!! for Mrs otherwise there would also be a parsing problem with Miss. As I said below, probably better just to remove Mrs and have only Ms for a married lady.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to differentiate between Mr and Mrs using the **Terms attribute**.

```
public enum TitleBot
{
    [Terms("Mr")]
    Mr=1,
    [Terms("Mrs")]
    Mrs,
    Ms,
    Miss,
    Dr
}
```

Selecting **Mr**
[image: Selecting Mr]

Selecting **Mrs**
[image: Selecting Mrs]

Answer (score 1):

It is because the bot is able to parse "Mr" in "Mrs" and so it is not able to select between "Mr" and "Mrs". So the bot is asking for user advice. After I do not know why it says it is an invalid option.

More or less Microsoft doc :

How bot parse user input in form dialog :

1. Break on case changes and underscore (_).
2. Generate each n-gram up to a maximum length.
3. Add "s?" to the end of each word (to support plurals).

Comment: Until I find a full solution I shall just remove Mrs from the enumeration then the problem will go away.